# Is the roof a floor?

Tags: saloon-tycoon

While playing through Saloon Tycoon for the first time, we weren't able to figure out whether the roof counts as a floor or not. There are two possibilities:

**1. The Roof is a Floor** 
In which case the tallest section would be:

Floor 3: Roof 
Floor 2: Another room 
Floor 1: Saloon

This is how we played it, since the roof is a tile just like any other it seemed like it should follow the same rules. This led to problems with the Luxury Suite, which is required to be on the third floor.

**2. The Roof is not a Floor**
In which case the tallest section could be:

Floor 4. Roof 
Floor 3. Another room 
Floor 2. Another room 
Floor 1. Saloon

This helps the Luxury Suite make sense, but it causes a conflict because the roof is now different than other tiles. It essentially becomes a fourth "floor".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The roof is neither a building nor a floor. You can build 3 tiles and when the 3rd one is finished with all cubes placed you get a roof.

This is covered on page 6 under the rules for finishing a tile:

> If the [finished] tile is on the 3rd floor, take the appropriate Roof tile (Small or Large), turn it over, place it on top and score +4 Reputation points.

Additionally, the example turn on page 8 illustrates this. The text and picture for step 4 shows a roof being added to a three-story building.

Comment: That would mean that a roof is also not a tile, since (as Gendolkari said) no building can be more than 3 tiles high. Is that correct?

Comment: Thanks. Someone pointed out this was covered in the rules. I'll accept this as the answer and probably edit in a reference to the rules.